# Python watch long running process, alert after so many minutes?

Tags: python, multithreading, watch

I'm working with Python and Jython to deploy applications to WebSphere. However, we are running into an issue with the WAS libraries where calls to these actions will sometimes take up to 30 minutes to execute. In order to troubleshoot this issue, I need to be able to keep tabs on if a process is still executing after so many minutes and, if so, send an alert.

I'm assuming I will need to put the call in a separate thread and watch it, but I have no experience with multithreading. What is the best way to do so and are there any gotchas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a built-in [`Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) class which will handle the threading stuff for you:

```
import threading

def after_2_minutes():
   if process_still_running():
       print "ALERT!!"

# start a timer in the background that waits 2 minutes
threading.Timer(2 * 60, after_2_minutes).start()

# start the process
foo.bar()
```

Gotchas: `after_30_minutes` will run in a separate thread, so as with any thread, you have to make sure that its actions don't interfere with your other threads (although you can manipulate simple data structures without problems due to the Global interpreter lock in CPython).

Comment: What's the best way to do the process_still_running() bit?

Comment: For example, I'm calling AdminControl.stopServer(jvm, node) to invoke a stop (here's where the 30 minute delay occasionally pops up). What would be the best thing to wrap around the call so that I can watch it and see if it's still running?

Comment: @user1311228: You start the timer before you start the process (for example with a 2 minute interval). Then if the timer function gets called, 2 minutes have passed and the process should have finished by now or something.

Comment: I understand that. But how do I check if the AdminControl.startServer() process has been completed? Do I need to fork it into its own subprocess, its own thead, do something magical with elves, etc

Comment: @user: Sorry, that's totally unrelated to the original question and highly dependent on the architecture of your software. You might want to ask a new question with a lot more information if you need help with that :)